# Using Simple Injector to register ISolrAbstractResponseParser<>

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am trying to update my code to use the latest version of Simple Injector.

Old code:

```
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(
    typeof(ISolrAbstractResponseParser<>), 
    typeof(DefaultResponseParser<>));
```

New code, not working:

```
container.Register(typeof(ISolrAbstractResponseParser<>), new[]
{
    typeof(ISolrAbstractResponseParser<>).Assembly,
    typeof(MultiResponseParser<>).Assembly
});
```

Getting this error:

```
SimpleInjector.ActivationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=The constructor of type SolrOperationsFactory<LemmaDocument> contains the parameter with name 'responseParser' and type ISolrAbstractResponseParser<LemmaDocument> that is not registered. 
  Please ensure ISolrAbstractResponseParser<LemmaDocument> is registered, or change the constructor of SolrOperationsFactory<LemmaDocument>.

  Source=SimpleInjector
  StackTrace:
       at SimpleInjector.Container.ThrowParameterTypeMustBeRegistered(InjectionTargetInfo target)
       at SimpleInjector.Advanced.DefaultDependencyInjectionBehavior.GetInstanceProducerFor(InjectionConsumerInfo consumer)
       at SimpleInjector.Advanced.DefaultDependencyInjectionBehavior.BuildExpression(InjectionConsumerInfo consumer)
       at SimpleInjector.ContainerOptions.BuildParameterExpression(InjectionConsumerInfo consumer)
       at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildConstructorParameters(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, ConstructorInfo constructor)
       at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildNewExpression(Type serviceType, Type implementationType)
       at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildTransientExpression[TService,TImplementation]()
       at SimpleInjector.Lifestyles.TransientLifestyle.TransientLifestyleRegistration`2.BuildExpression()
       at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildExpression(InstanceProducer producer)
       at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildExpressionInternal()
       at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
       at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildExpression()
       at SimpleInjector.Advanced.DefaultDependencyInjectionBehavior.BuildExpression(InjectionConsumerInfo consumer)
       at SimpleInjector.ContainerOptions.BuildParameterExpression(InjectionConsumerInfo consumer)
       at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildConstructorParameters(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, ConstructorInfo constructor)
       at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildNewExpression(Type serviceType, Type implementationType)
       at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildTransientExpression[TService,TImplementation]()
       at SimpleInjector.Lifestyles.TransientLifestyle.TransientLifestyleRegistration`2.BuildExpression()
       at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildExpression(InstanceProducer producer)
       at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildExpressionInternal()
       at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
       at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildExpression()
       at SimpleInjector.Advanced.DefaultDependencyInjectionBehavior.BuildExpression(InjectionConsumerInfo consumer)
       at SimpleInjector.ContainerOptions.BuildParameterExpression(InjectionConsumerInfo consumer)
       at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildConstructorParameters(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, ConstructorInfo constructor)
       at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildNewExpression(Type serviceType, Type implementationType)
       at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildTransientExpression[TService,TImplementation]()
       at SimpleInjector.Lifestyles.TransientLifestyle.TransientLifestyleRegistration`2.BuildExpression()
       at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildExpression(InstanceProducer producer)
       at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildExpressionInternal()
       at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
       at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildExpression()
       at SimpleInjector.Advanced.DefaultDependencyInjectionBehavior.BuildExpression(InjectionConsumerInfo consumer)
       at SimpleInjector.ContainerOptions.BuildParameterExpression(InjectionConsumerInfo consumer)
       at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildConstructorParameters(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, ConstructorInfo constructor)
       at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildNewExpression(Type serviceType, Type implementationType)
       at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildTransientExpression[TService,TImplementation]()
       at SimpleInjector.Lifestyles.TransientLifestyle.TransientLifestyleRegistration`2.BuildExpression()
       at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildExpression(InstanceProducer producer)
       at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildExpressionInternal()
       at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
       at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildExpression()
       at SimpleInjector.Advanced.DefaultDependencyInjectionBehavior.BuildExpression(InjectionConsumerInfo consumer)
       at SimpleInjector.ContainerOptions.BuildParameterExpression(InjectionConsumerInfo consumer)
       at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildConstructorParameters(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, ConstructorInfo constructor)
       at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildNewExpression(Type serviceType, Type implementationType)
       at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildTransientExpression[TService,TImplementation]()
       at SimpleInjector.Lifestyles.TransientLifestyle.TransientLifestyleRegistration`2.BuildExpression()
       at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildExpression(InstanceProducer producer)
       at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildExpressionInternal()
       at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
       at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildExpression()
       at SimpleInjector.Advanced.DefaultDependencyInjectionBehavior.BuildExpression(InjectionConsumerInfo consumer)
       at SimpleInjector.ContainerOptions.BuildParameterExpression(InjectionConsumerInfo consumer)
       at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildConstructorParameters(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, ConstructorInfo constructor)
       at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildNewExpression(Type serviceType, Type implementationType)
       at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildTransientExpression[TService,TImplementation]()
       at SimpleInjector.Lifestyles.TransientLifestyle.TransientLifestyleRegistration`2.BuildExpression()
       at SimpleInjector.Registration.BuildExpression(InstanceProducer producer)
       at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildExpressionInternal()
       at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
       at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildInstanceCreator()
       at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildAndReplaceInstanceCreatorAndCreateFirstInstance()
       at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance()
       at SimpleInjector.Container.GetInstanceForRootType[TService]()
       at SimpleInjector.Container.GetInstance[TService]()
       at Goo.FileMonitor.FileMonitor.Start() in C:\projects\Gyldendal.Goo\Source\Goo.FileMonitor\Goo.FileMonitor\FileMonitor.cs:line 23
       at Goo.FileMonitor.Program.<>c.<Main>b__0_3(FileMonitor tc) in C:\projects\Gyldendal.Goo\Source\Goo.FileMonitor\Goo.FileMonitor\Program.cs:line 14
       at Topshelf.ServiceConfiguratorExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`1.<WhenStarted>b__0(T service, HostControl control)
       at Topshelf.Builders.DelegateServiceBuilder`1.DelegateServiceHandle.Start(HostControl hostControl)
       at Topshelf.Hosts.ConsoleRunHost.Run()
  InnerException:
```

The interface is declared in SolrNet but used in my code.

container.RegisterOpenGeneric has been removed from Simple Injector. [Link to documentation](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#generics)

Simple Injector is failing on in this class:

```
/// <summary>
    /// An adapter for SolrNet.Impl.SolrMoreLikeThisHandlerQueryResultsParser to work around a limitation in SimpleInjector where
    /// arrays of open generic types cannot be injected.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    public class SolrMoreLikeThisHandlerQueryResultsParserAdapter<T> : SolrMoreLikeThisHandlerQueryResultsParser<T>
    {
        public SolrMoreLikeThisHandlerQueryResultsParserAdapter(IEnumerable<ISolrAbstractResponseParser<T>> parsers) : base(parsers.ToArray())
        {
        }
    }
```

Is there still a problem with Simple Injector and injecting arrays of open generic types?

***** **I am giving up on updating my project to use Simple Injector => 3.0** *****
Should I delete this question?

Comment: Can you post the exact compile error that you get from C# when using the `container.RegisterOpenGeneric` code?

Comment: I am not getting an error using container.RegisterOpenGeneric. My old code is working but container.RegisterOpenGeneric as been removed in the new version of Simple Injector

Comment: Which version are you using now?

Comment: Do note that the RegisterOpenGeneric extension method is [still there](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/blob/43b21b0c1a02c838e570f3bf8a050f89b95a1dec/src/SimpleInjector.NET/Extensions/OpenGenericRegistrationExtensions.cs#L114) but you should get a compiler obsolete error when using it. The compiler error should inform you about what you should do instead. I'm interested to see why you aren't getting that particular compile error.

Comment: I am getting the warning and I am using version 3.3.2.

Comment: And what does the warning say?

Comment: This extension method has been removed. Please use Container.Register(Type, Type) to register a generic type. In case this registration acts as fallback registration (in case an explicit registration is missing), please use Container.RegisterConditional(Type, Type, c => !c.Handled) instead.

I have tried many examples inspired from the documentation but I am unable to get it right

Answer (score 2):

As you already stated, the compiler error is stating:

> This extension method has been removed. Please use Container.Register(Type, Type) to register a generic type. In case this registration acts as fallback registration (in case an explicit registration is missing), please use Container.RegisterConditional(Type, Type, c => !c.Handled) instead.

Long story short, replace the call to `RegisterOpenGeneric` with `Register` as shown in the next example:

```
container.Register(
    typeof(ISolrAbstractResponseParser<>), 
    typeof(DefaultResponseParser<>));
```

Comment: That was the first I did, but I am getting the error you can see in the stacktrace

Comment: Tha'ts because you didn't switch to `Register(Type, Type)` as the error explained, but to `Register(Type, IEnumerable<Assembly>)`. The former maps an open generic abstraction to an open generic implementation, while the latter batch-registers all non-generic implementations found in the supplied assemblies that implement a closed generic version of the supplied abstraction (which will probably be *none* in your case).

Comment: I started with Register(type, type) and then I tried many other functions in the API.

Comment: You should try `Register(Type, Type)` again. That should work

Comment: I have now included the code that is causing the error

Comment: It's unclear to what it is you are trying to achieve and why you are having these problems. Can you post a complete reproducible minimal program that shows the problem?